# conversion of react columns data to ant design columns data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I am learning react as well as ant design. I have to convert some react table code to an ant design table. Here is my react code below. How can I convert that in ant design? Please advise.

```
getTableColumns(){
return[
 Header: "A",
            accessor: "A",
            getProps: (state, rowInfo) => ({
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: (rowInfo && rowInfo.original.useCase === Detail.notDefined ? 'red' : null)
                }
            }),
            width: 100
        },
  //here I have tried to convert it in ant design, but it is not working
        {
            title: "B",
            dataIndex: "B",
            key: "B",
            render: (d) => {
                if (Array.isArray(this.getB(d))) return this.getB(d).join(",")
                else return JSON.stringify(this.getB(d))
            }
        }
       {
            title: "Edit",
            dataIndex: "edit",
            key:'edit',
            render: (text, record) =>
            console.log(record.original),
            <a href={`${getApi}/${record.original.parent}/task/${record.original.id}/edit`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Edit</a>,
            width: 60
        }
    ]
```

and my `antd table` is formed like below:

```
<div className="article_full">
  <h2>DETAILS</h2>
  <Table
    rowKey={row => `${row.id}`}
    columns={this.getTableColumns()}
    dataSource={items}
    onChange={this.filter}
    Pagination
    onChange={this.onPageChange}
    total={50}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: What does your data (items) look like?